# Masonry just.. isn't doing anything

Tags: jquery-masonry

I have Masonry here:

http://news.enigma-tech.co.uk/

..supposedly.

It's just not working. I have package installed locally, and in script tags in the header.

The I have `<div id="container" class="js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 472, "itemSelector": ".box-wrap", "gutter": 12 }'>`

But it's just not having any affect. No sign it's even trying - the gutter isn't there even.

First time with Masonry, please go easy on me!

Oh, I also tried initialising with jQuery, but it didn't make any difference.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Anyone got any suggestions? It's like the script just.. isn't running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `gutter: 12` needs to be `"gutter": 12`. Masonry was complaining about a parsing error.

Comment: D'oh. Sorry, I had that right earlier. Fixed now, still doesn't work.

Comment: Brian, any further tips?

Comment: 1) all your `<article>`s are outside the masonry container. must be inside `#container`. 2) itemSelector must be `article`, not `.item`. 3) `article` is displaying as blocks (100% width). they won't lay out. you need to give a new css style that says `article {display: inline-block}`.

Comment: Okay, then my problems a little different. I probably have one too many `</div>`s - it seems like `container` is being closed too soon.

Comment: And yet it isn't. `header.php` ends with `<div id="container" class="js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "itemSelector": ".item" }'>`, then on the front page, header is called, and I have the first `item`, 3 divs open, 3 divs close. Then a while loop generates more `item`s. Why are those suddenly outside the `container`?!

Comment: Fixed by moving masonry init to the `wrap`. There's something screwy in Wordpress' loop that kicked the loop posts out of `container`. Thanks :)